# Add a value to time

Tags: java, android

How to get system date and time.After getting time add 4hour to that time.Time Format is 12 Hour.I tried Like this

```
enter code here
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    String strTime = dataFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
```

Example:I given 10.30AM add 4hour.I need 2.30PM

Comment: Try swapping round those last two lines.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what's going wrong?

Comment: Below code is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
SimpleDateFormat dataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String strTime = dataFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```